# Zum einprägen oder zum Einprägen?

Tags: capitalization

Welche Schreibweise ist richtig?

> Einfache Sätze zum einprägen

oder

> Einfache Sätze zum Einprägen

Ich würde *einprägen* eher als Verb sehen, denke es könnte hier aber auch als Nomen stehen. Geht beides? Welches ist gebräuchlicher?

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt Sätze bei denen man selbst entscheiden kann, ob ein Wort groß- oder kleingeschrieben wird. So ist etwa in folgendem Satz, je nachdem wir man ihn versteht, beides möglich.

> Die Kinder lernen schreiben/Schreiben. [Quelle](https://www.sekretaria.de/bueroorganisation/rechtschreibung/substantivierung-gross-kleinschreibung/)

Mit Hilfe einiger "Hinweise" kann man jedoch erkennen, wann eine Großschreibung erforderlich ist.

Generell gilt: Wörter die keine Substantive sind schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive gebraucht werden. Dies wird auch als Substantivierung, bzw. Nominalisierung bezeichnet.

Wann ein Verb, Adjektiv, Pronomen, etc. substantiviert wird beschreibt [§58 des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf). Man erkennt sie:

> a) an einem vorausgehenden Artikel (der, die, das; ein, eine, ein),Pronomen (dieser,  jener,  welcher,  mein,  kein,  etwas,  nichts,  alle,  einige...) oder unbestimmten Zahlwort (ein paar, genug, viel, wenig...), die sich auf das substantivierte Wort beziehen;
>
> b) an  einem  vorangestellten adjektivischen  Attribut  oder  einem  nachgestellten Attribut, das sich auf das substantivierte Wort bezieht;
>
> c) an ihrer Funktion als kasusbestimmtes Satzglied oder kasusbestimmtes Attribut.

In diesem Fall ist also zu entscheiden, ob einprägen/Einprägen hier ein substantivierter Infinitiv ist oder nicht. Den entscheidenden Hinweis gibt bereits die Präposition "zum", da nach ihr eine Substantivierung erfolgt. Vergleiche etwa den Satz:

> Das ist zum Lachen.

oder

> Zum Telefonieren, zum Schreiben

Ein weiterer Hinweis für die Substantivierung ist außerdem, wenn man dem Wort eine Apposition wie "von" folgen lassen kann.

> Einfache Sätze zum Einprägen von Vokabeln.

Comment: Hier könnte man noch nennen, dass *zum* die Kurzform von *zu dem* oder *zu einem* ist, und somit, o.g. §58 a) folgend, einen vorangestellten Artikel besitzt.

Comment: @MarkLösche, niemand nie sagt *zu dem Einprägen*. So ein Lötzinn. Aber ich fürchte, im Duden würden entsprechende Beispiele genannt, die mtwde bekannt sind, und gehe daher nicht von Betrug aus. Zudem Sehe ich aber nicht, dass Präpositionen in 58 a) genannt werden; Ob *von Vokabeln* ein attributives Adjektiv ist, sei dahingestellt, denn ... wie auch immer. Eine andere Regel besagt, Nomen, die adverbial verwendet werden, werden klein geschrieben (beispielsweise *beispielsweise*); Ich sehe den Unterschied nicht, da im Bsp.-Satz gar kein Verb steht. Ich finde das Bsp auch stilitisch unsauber.

Comment: Antwort wäre also: In diesem Fall ist beides möglich und die beiden Lösungmöglichkeiten sind gleichwertig. ?

Comment: Nein, die Lösung ist wie @mtwde oben schrieb die Variante mit Großschreibung.